# Spring Circular dependency Injection for two classes using constructor injection

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have two classes like

```
class A
{
  //constructor with B as argument
}

class B
{
 //constructor with A as argument
}
```

In xml

```
<bean name="a" class="A">
    <constructor-arg ref="b"/>
</bean>

<bean name="b" class="B">
    <constructor-arg ref="a"/>
</bean>
```

This scenario is not working.Is there any alternative to this scenario.

Comment: If it is `null` you aren't using the instance configured in the spring context but are probably creating a new one yourself or are using it from a place where it isn't available yet (constructor for instance). Next to that you circular reference which IMHO is always a code smell (not to say bad design!) and reason for refactoring.

Comment: @M.Deinum please check updated code once.Actually here i am using constructor injection

Comment: That will never be possible as Spring won't be able to construct either A or B. Circular dependencies will only work with setter based injection.

Comment: you mean my previous code will work ?

Comment: It MIGHT work depending on how and where you are using the dependencies. If they are used to early they aren't available. But as mentioned circular references are a cause for refactoring in my book.

Comment: i didn't get u.Can u explain clearly.Is there any alternative to this type of situation

Comment: Don't do circular dependencies if you have it will only work with setter based injection. If you try to use the instance of B (in A) inside the constructor it will not work because the dependency hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60362/discussion-between-psr-and-m-deinum).